# How to Use data.table dcast Renaming on one Aggregation Function

Tags: r, data.table, dcast

`dcast.data.table` automatically renames columns when multiple aggregation functions are used. How can I use this rename when I use only one function?

```
DT = melt(as.data.table(ChickWeight), id=2:4)
% automatic rename
data.table::dcast(DT, Time ~ variable, fun=list(mean, sd))
% copies only the factor level
data.table::dcast(DT, Time ~ variable, fun=mean)
```

Comment: Probably not the answer you're looking for, but maybe worth nothing you could rename as desired to the right of `~` i.e. `data.table::dcast(DT, Time ~ paste0('mean_', variable), fun = mean)`

Comment: A workaround would be to supply a second function and then remove the extra column:  `data.table::dcast(DT, Time ~ variable, fun=list(mean, sum))[, -3]
`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks! However, this doesn't use the build in naming from `dcast` which adds, for instance, the level to the corresponding column.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you, too! I thought also about this workaround. However, when using large datasets with an undefined number of levels in `variable` this is time consuming and I have to take care to delete the correct columns. Currently, I see no alternative.